# Format Document for F#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, format

I'd like to format the document: give it indentation and stuff like that.

`Ctrl K` + `Ctrl D/F` in Visual Studio doesn't work for F#, does anybody have any workaround for that? It does work for C# though...

**EDIT:** What I'd like to do is to copy-paste some code from an external source. I usually use `Ctrl K` + `Ctrl D` to format it, and it works for C#. However, in an .fs file, it doesn't seem to work. On top of that, indentation seems to be pretty much a must-have for F#...

Comment: In `#light` mode, F# code is [indentation-aware](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2006/08/24/715626.aspx), so auto-indentation would be (1) less useful; (2) error-prone.

Comment: And non-light mode is not really supported, not since VS2010.

Comment: Actually, if used with care, I believe Emacs can format F# pretty well (assuming, as @bytebuster noted, some basic meaningful pre-formatting). I might be wrong, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I'm neither using FSI nor do I have `#light` in my code; doesn't that mean my code shouldn't be in `#light` mode? What's this `#light` mode anyway? (sorry I'm kinda new to F#)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# is indentation sensitive, so if you copy valid code from one location to another, the only thing that you might need to do is to make sure it has the right offset from the left side. For example, say you have:

```
let test () = 
  printfn "Hello world" // (*)

let another () = 
  for i in 0 .. 10 do
    test()              // (#)
  printfn "finished"
```

Now, if you wanted to copy the line `(*)` and use it instead of a call to `test`, just Copy & Paste would turn your code into the following:

```
let another () = 
  for i in 0 .. 10 do
  printfn "Hello world" // (*)
  printfn "finished"
```

This has a different meaning though! It repeates both of the `printfn` lines 10 times. So, instead what you would want to get is this:

```
let another () = 
  for i in 0 .. 10 do
    printfn "Hello world" // (*)
  printfn "finished"
```

The way to do Copy & Paste in Visual Studio to keep the same meaning of code is to paste the copied code as usual (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and then, while the code is still selected, correct the indentation. To indent the code further use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and to indent it less far use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This way, you can use Copy and Paste for F# code just fine. You do not need to reformat the entire block, because valid F# code copied to another place will automatically be well formatted. You just need to fix the indentation.

Regarding the `#light` mode mentioned in comments - in earlier versions of F#, it was possible to use additional keywords and semicolons instead of indentation-sensitive mode. The modern indentation-sensitive style was called `#light`, but it is now default and you do not need to worry about the legacy style.

Comment: Using Shift+Tab can cause indentation errors when the first line begins with an opening bracket, both in VS 2010 and VS 2012. Such errors may be avoided by never writing code immediately after an opening brace. However, this workaround looks awkward and does not correspond to the ["recommended" style](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/expert-fsharp-draft/FormattingConventions.doc)...

Comment: The best way to move code around in F# is: 1) Use 'SHIFT+ALT+DOWNARROW' to define an offset line (a vertical line with zero width on the left side of the code block you want to move), and 2) _then_ use 'TAB' or 'SHIFT+TAB' to move the offset line (and thereby also move the code) back and forth. This guarantees that, no matter what coding style you use, the indentations inside the moving block will always remain correct.

Comment: What about formatting code?? (Not just indentation, but all the other things like number of spaces, and when to start a new line)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the only answer is to use one of these:

https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/24ef5c87-b4e3-4c3b-b126-1064cc66e148

https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting

handles spaces and such